# Wrong currencies in dynamic stock quote from Yahoo Finance in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, currency-formatting, stockquotes

I am doing a dynamic stock quote in Power BI and I want to pull data on stocks with various currencies. My issue is then when I pull the numbers, the comma is missing:
[image]

instead of being 86,699997 it deletes the comma so that the value is just 86699997 - does anyone know how to overcome this when extracting the data?

Comment: not familiar with power bi, but it is common issue when comma is used as thousands separator, not decimals. maybe you have to find some way how to switch decimal separator from dot to comma

Comment: In Power Query, add the `culture` argument to the `Change Type` step -- probably should be `"en-US"`